# Sinatra Error: Unable to activate sinatra-contrib-1.4.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

Trying to run a Sinatra app and I keep getting this error:

```
/Users/matthewsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2064:in `raise_if_conflicts': 
Unable to activate sinatra-contrib-1.4.2, because tilt-2.0.1 conflicts with tilt (~> 1.3) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/matthewsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1262:in `activate'
from /Users/matthewsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:196:in `rescue in try_activate'
from /Users/matthewsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:193:in `try_activate'
from /Users/matthewsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/matthewsmith/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from app.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.5'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'pg'
```

I tried including

```
gem 'tilt', '~> 1.3'
```

in the Gemfile as well but that didn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  I removed Tilt 2.0.1 and my application works as expected.

Remove gem:

```
$ gem uninstall tilt -v 2.0.1
Successfully uninstalled tilt-2.0.1

$ bundle install
Resolving dependencies...
...
Bundle complete! 9 Gemfile dependencies, 17 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Restarted application (via Pow):

```
~/app-dir$ touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifying this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sinatra-contrib', github: 'sinatra/sinatra-contrib'
```

and running

```
bundle update
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks.  For some reason I have two versions of Tilt showing in my Gemfile.lock.  One on its own and one as a Sinatra dependency.  If I uninstall version 2.0.1 (the latest update) the app runs, but every time I bundle update I then have to uninstall the updated version of Tilt.

Comment: `bundle update` re-resolves the gem dependencies and rewrites your Gemfile.lock. Before you run it ensure that you only have the gems that you need in your Gemfile, which should ensure you only have the version of tilt that you need. Good luck :)

Comment: @MatthewSmith How did you get on?

Comment: @MatthewSmith, For some reason, bundler just gets stuck on this step:

"Fetching git://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib.git"